# How to open just only the modal which is clicked

Tags: firebase, react-native, bootstrap-modal, reactstrap

I'm using React and Firebase to make CRUD website.

I made a table using reactstrap and try to use modal for showing contents of each table cell.

However, I ran into a error that opening every table cell's modals just by clicking one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DWUx.png)

If you look into a image above you can check there are several table cells. Once I click just one it goes like following image. Opening every single modals.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTAHD.png)

I will put my code only about those modal part.

...

```js
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
  
  ...
  
<td>
  <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}>내용 보기</Button>
    <Modal isOpen={modal} modalTransition={{ timeout: 700 }} backdropTransition={{ timeout: 1300 }} toggle={toggle}>
      <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{value.name}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          {value.description}
        </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
</td>
```

I think I should use {value.id} for showing only modal I clicked because it has to be specific. So I tried few changes but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should rework your structure a bit
const [modals, setModals] = useState({});

modals should be object of value's id (so it will be object of value id and bool)
so

```
{
  1: true,
  2: false,
}
```

And you should rework jsx code to
onClick={() => toggle(value.id)} and isOpen={modals[value.id]}

I can't see full you code, so can't write correct variables what you use in code, but here you should be able to get idea

Also you can use modalId as state

const [modalId, setModalId] = useState(-1);
and in toggle function update new id in state